# Java date older than 1923

Tags: java, java.util.date

So I have a strange problem, I have a java swing application that has the date 10/11/1922 00:00:00 MST but when it sends that date to my backend glassfish server via RMI the date becomes 10/10/1922 23:00:00 MST. So it is somehow losing an hour, is this a bug? I can't find anything on google that references this problem. If I do a date in 1923 it works fine I don't lose an hour. My client is running 1.6.0 patch 30 and my server is running 1.6.0 patch 17.

Comment: Do the two Java applications use the same Locale, notably timezone?

Comment: They could have different timezone information for that period. Historical timezones are a messy business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've seen a question like this before--essentially there was a shift in the definition of timezones at that point in history, or something like that, so that hour actually *never* existed. I think, in fact, Jon Skeet was the one to locate the error (in the previous SO question). I can't find it right now, I have to go to lunch, but I think it's out there :D

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479

Comment: It's not exactly the same issue, but the discussion has some useful information.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a similar question here: [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479) this showed the error arose due to time zone changes. Doing a quick Google I found for example in the UK in 1922 the times were forwarded by an 1h to compensate for daylight time savings see here: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=136&year=1922. I stand corrected though.

EDIT:

I think I found the exact change you talked about, as yours is actually set back by an hour and not forwarded like I said in my original post: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=286&year=1922